# How to pass data from child to parent component using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a Parent component and couple of child components. I need to disable or enable the button in the parent based on the ErrorComponent. If there is an error then I disable the button or else I enable it. I believe we can pass callbacks from the child to parent and let the parent know and update the button property. I need to know how to do the same using react hooks? I tried few examples but in vain. There is no event on error component. If there is an error (props.errorMessage) then I need to pass some data to parent so that I can disable the button. Any help is highly appreciated

```
export const Parent: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
....
const createContent = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    {<ErrorPanel message={props.errorMessage}/>}
    <AnotherComponent/>
  );
}
return (
<Button onClick={onSubmit} disabled={}>My Button</Button>
{createContent()}
);
};
export const ErrorPanel: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  if (props.message) {
    return (
        <div>{props.message}</div>
    );
  }
  return null;
};
```

Comment: `disabled={!!props.errorMessage}`

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but this errorMessage returns as part of an API response and by the time I get the response the button is already rendered.

Comment: it doesn't matter - after `props` change `<Parent/>` is rerendered (all FC code run), `disabled` should be updated, `<Button/>` disabled .... passing this prop down to child only to to pass it back into parrent is uneccessary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `useEffect` hook in this case, to set the `disabled` state depending on the `message` props. You can see the whole working app here: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-glade-lfnxk?file=/src/App.tsx)

`ErrorPanel` component will look like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

interface IPropTypes {
  setDisabled(disabled:boolean): void;
  message?: string;
}

const ErrorPanel = ({ setDisabled, message }: IPropTypes) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    if (message) {
      setDisabled(true);
    } else {
      setDisabled(false);
    }
  }, [message, setDisabled]);

  if (message) {
    return <div>Error: {message}</div>;
  }
  return null;
};

export default ErrorPanel;
```

So depending on the `message` prop, whenever it 'exists', I set the `disabled` prop to true by manipulating the `setDisabled` function passed by the prop.

And to make this work, `Parent` component looks like this:

```
import React, { MouseEvent, useState } from "react";

import ErrorPanel from "./ErrorPanel";

interface IPropTypes {
  errorMessage?: string;
}

const Parent = ({ errorMessage }: IPropTypes) => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const createContent = () => {
    return <ErrorPanel setDisabled={setDisabled} message={errorMessage} />;
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e: MouseEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Submit");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleSubmit} disabled={disabled}>
        My Button
      </button>
      <br />
      <br />
      {createContent()}
    </>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```