# How to pass data to {props.children}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

On my follow up question from here : [How to pass data from child to parent component using react hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62315572/how-to-pass-data-from-child-to-parent-component-using-react-hooks?noredirect=1#comment110219286_62315572)
I have another issue. 
Below is the component structure

```
export const Parent: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(false);
const createContent = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Authorization>
    {<ErrorPanel message={errorMessage} setDisabled={setDisabled}/>}
    <MyChildComponent/>
    </<Authorization>
  );
}

return (
   <Button onClick={onSubmit} disabled={disabled}>My Button</Button>
   {createContent()}
 );
};

const Authorization: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(false);
const render = (errorMessage : JSX.Element): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <>
      {<ErrorPanel message={errorMessage} setDisabled={setDisabled}/>}
      </>
    );
  };

return (
    <>
    <PageLoader
      queryResult={apiQuery}
      renderPage={render}
    />
    {props.children}
    </>
  );
};
```

How do I pass the disabled state value from Authorization component to my child which is invoked by
`{props.children}`
I tried React.cloneElement & React.createContext but I'm not able to get the value disabled to the `MyChildComponent`. I could see the value for disabled as `true` once the errorMessage is set through the `ErrorPanel` in the Authorization component.
Do I need to have `React.useEffect` in the Authorization Component?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `React.cloneElement` to `React.Children.map` to pass on the `disabled prop` to the immediate children components

```
const Authorization: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(false);
    const render = (errorMessage : JSX.Element): JSX.Element => {
        return (
          <>
          {<ErrorPanel message={errorMessage} setDisabled={setDisabled}/>}
          </>
        );
      };

    return (
        <>
        <PageLoader
          queryResult={apiQuery}
          renderPage={render}
        />
        {React.Children.map(props.children, child => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, { disabled })
         })}
        </>
      );
};
```

UPDATE:

Since you wish to update the parent state to, you should store the state and parent and update it there itself, instead of storing the state in child component too.

```
export const Parent: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(false);
const createContent = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Authorization setDisabled={setDisabled}>
    {<ErrorPanel message={errorMessage} disabled={disabled} setDisabled={setDisabled}/>}
    <MyChildComponent disabled={disabled}/>
    </<Authorization>
  );
}

return (
   <Button onClick={onSubmit} disabled={disabled}>My Button</Button>
   {createContent()}
 );
};

const Authorization: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
const render = (errorMessage : JSX.Element): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <>
      {<ErrorPanel message={errorMessage} disabled={props.disabled} setDisabled={props.setDisabled}/>}
      </>
    );
  };

return (
    <>
    <PageLoader
      queryResult={apiQuery}
      renderPage={render}
    />
    {props.children}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This works perfect, but catch for me is I don't need to send it to the children but to the parent as you can see the Button component is on the parent component. I was wrong about saying sending the data to my child Component. So, in that case I need to use only the React.useEffect in the Authorization component. Am I right?

Comment: You need to pass on a function as a prop from the parent and then inside useEffect call it to update the parent . However I will advice you to store the state only in the parent and update it from child if you have to and pass it on as a prop to the AuthorizationComponent

Comment: Glad to hace helped.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `React.Children` API with `React.cloneElement`:

```
const Authorization = ({ children }) => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(false);

  const render = (errorMessage) => {
    return (
      <>{<ErrorPanel message={errorMessage} setDisabled={setDisabled} />}</>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <PageLoader queryResult={apiQuery} renderPage={render} />
      {React.Children.map(children, (child) =>
        React.cloneElement(child, { disabled })
      )}
    </>
  );
};


// | 
// v
// It will inject `disabled` prop to every component's child:
<>
  <ErrorPanel
    disabled={disabled}
    message={errorMessage}
    setDisabled={setDisabled}
  />
  <MyChildComponent disabled={disabled} />
</>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This works perfect, but catch for me is I don't need to send it to the children but to the parent as you can see the ```Button``` component is on the parent component. I was wrong about sending the data to my child Component. So, in that case I need to use only the React.useEffect. Am I right?

Comment: Best answer. Thanks.

Comment: Nice approach, works perfect to me to use it into a Dialog, I send a function to close the Dialog component